# Go back to previous application after exit?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have a situation which would be easily solved if we were using android as originally designed (and partially coded).  Unfortunately, we're going the MS C++ on Windows Enterprise route because of some vital legacy applications.  Basically we're coding a launcher that needs to start an application and when that application is closed, the user is brought back to the previous application (the one that launched the 2nd application).  I hope that makes sense.

I know this can be done because I vaguely recall an application I used in college for taking exams did something like this, but when I do a search all I get are android solutions.  Any help or links to libraries to look at will be wonderful.

Comment: What you can do is to have the launcher use [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) and then do a [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) on the process handle. This will suspend execution of that thread until the process exits. If it then continues to run, you know the other application has finished. [You can see an example of those two functions in the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

there are may ways here are 2 most obvious:

1. most easy and safe way is that launched application send message to launcher that it is closing

   - but you need to add code to that application
   - you can use windows messaging or mailbox or semaphores or whatever else.
2. launcher periodically checks if there is active window handle of the right class/type/GUID.

   - if not then pop up the restore/maximize or visibility and set focus to it self.
   - you need to know what class is that app of yours
   - of course if there are more apps of the same class/id/type/GUID this way you cannot know which one is which